# Matplotlib scatter 3D button_press_event give wrong index based on scatter axis place on subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter

I display some points on a 3D scatter subplot, and i'd like to highlight the point that is clicked on. But ind["ind"][0] is giving a wrong index of the selected point based on a the place of the x axis (top or bottom) or y axis (left or right) on the graph. Thus, the hilighted points it not the one I click on.

Regards,

Matt

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Lx = 0.8
Ly = 0.5
n = 10
Nx = 8
Ny = 5
x = np.linspace(0, Lx, Nx)
y = np.linspace(0, Ly, Ny)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

#visualisaiton 3D
fig = plt.figure('Visualisation 3D')
ax2 = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')

ac_x, ac_y = 1, 1

sc = ax2.scatter(X.ravel(), Y.ravel(), np.zeros(Nx * Ny), picker=True)
ac = ax2.scatter(x[ac_x], y[ac_y], 0, 'r', s=50)

def click(event, ind):
    i = ind["ind"][0]
    xx, yy, zz = sc._offsets3d

    def find_nearest(array, value):
        array = np.asarray(array)
        idx = (np.abs(array - value)).argmin()
        return idx

    ac_x = np.where(x == xx[i])[0]
    ac_y = np.where(y == yy[i])[0]

    print('xx[i], yy[i]: (%.2f, %.2f)' % (xx[i], yy[i]))

    print('Click at: (%.2f, %.2f)' % (xx[i], yy[i]))
    print('%s click: button=%d, x=%d, y=%d, xdata=%f, ydata=%f' %
          ('double' if event.dblclick else 'single', event.button,
           event.x, event.y, event.xdata, event.ydata))

    ac_act = ax2.scatter(x[ac_x], y[ac_y], 0, 'r', s=50)

    print('index (%d, %d) position: (%.2f, %.2f)' % (ac_x, ac_y, x[ac_x], y[ac_y]))

def on_click(event):
    if event.inaxes == ax2:
        cont2, ind2 = sc.contains(event)
        if cont2:
            click(event, ind2)
            fig.canvas.draw_idle()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_click)


plt.show()
```

Working exemple:

[image]

NOT working:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I have also been having some trouble with getting the correct indices from Path3DCollection. After doing some digging, I found out that the data array is resorted based on the z coordinate. To get the original indices, you need to access the member _z_markers_idx, which is unfortunately protected.

In the file:

```
mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\art3d.py
```

I added the following getter to class Path3DCollection:

```
def get_z_markers_idx(self):
    return self._z_markers_idx
```

You would then be able to fetch the correct index with:

```
def click(event, ind):
    i = sc.get_z_markers_idx()[ind["ind"][0]]
```